# Why am I getting a connection refused error when using the Deadweight gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rake file for deadweight looks like

> > task :deadweight do
> >
> > > dw = Deadweight.new
> > >
> > > dw.stylesheets =["/stylesheets/application.css"]
> > >
> > > dw.pages = ["/"]
> > >
> > > puts dw.run
> >
> > end

dw.run is giving following error:

> Connection refused - connect(2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with deadweight, but it could be deadweight expects a running server at 0.0.0.0:3000.

From https://github.com/aanand/deadweight :

> Running rake deadweight will output all unused rules, one per line.
>   Note that it looks at `http://localhost:3000` by default, so you'll need
>   to have script/server (or whatever your server command looks like)
>   running.